# Zoom array of images in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, zooming

How i can zoom array of images? Now i can zoom image as a .gif

[image]

My code:

```
class ScrollImageViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollImage: UIScrollView!

    private var imageView: UIImageView!

    var imagesArray = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.scrollImage.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
        self.scrollImage.maximumZoomScale = 5.0

        for i in 0..<imagesArray.count {

            imageView = UIImageView()
            imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imagesArray[i]))
            imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            let xPosition = self.view.frame.width * CGFloat(i)
            imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: 0, width: self.scrollImage.frame.width, height: self.scrollImage.frame.height)

            scrollImage.contentSize.width = scrollImage.frame.width * CGFloat(i + 1)
            scrollImage.addSubview(imageView)
        }
    }

    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return imageView
    }
}
```

I tried lesson from raywenderlich, but they did not help me :(

I want to get result like a AirBnB or example:

Scrolling once and zoom in, zoom out, scrolling twice - zoom in, zoom out and so on

Comment: Unclear what you want. Code does not call `viewForZooming()`.

Comment: I want zoom each image in my scrollView, but now it's work as .gif. I can scroll image on left and right, but if i pinch to zoom i get curves images and my scrolling is stopped

Comment: Zoom image like a AirBnB

Comment: Did you find any solution?.

Answer (score 0):

You can check below framework

https://github.com/zvonicek/ImageSlideshow

It has a `FullScreenSlideshowViewController`class which can be used for your purpose, also it can be customised.